# Verilog Testbench module not found

Tags: verilog

I am trying to make my first program testbench and having an error calle " error: Unknown module type: circuit
2 error(s) during elaboration.

```
*** These modules were missing:
        circuit referenced 1 times.
***".
```

Can someone please help me with this? I tried different ways of calling the module.
Here is the code:

```
module circuit (a,b,c,d,o);
input a,b,c,d;
output o;
wire e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n;
not (e,a);
not (f,b);
not (g,c);
not (h,d);
and (I,e,g);
and (j,e,f,c,h);
and (k,a,f,g,h);
and (l,a,c);
and (m,b,g,d);
and (n,b,c,d);
or (o,i);
or (o,j);
or (o,k);
or (o,l);
or (o,m);
or (o,n);

endmodule
```

And here is the testbench code

```
module TB_circuit;  
reg a1,b1,c1,d1;
wire o1;
circuit my_module(a1,b1,c1,d1,o1);
initial
begin
a1=0;
c1=0;
#period;
end
endmodule
```

Both are different file but in same folder. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `period` as a `parameter` and set it to a numeric value, such as 50:

```
module TB_circuit;  
    reg a1,b1,c1,d1;
    wire o1;
    parameter period = 50;
    circuit my_module(a1,b1,c1,d1,o1);
initial
begin
    a1=0;
    c1=0;
    #period;
end
endmodule
```

Here is an example on [edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/Z3Za) which compiles.  It is free, but you do need to sign up for an account.